# How to set a child scene's Sprite2D Texture to a SubViewport?

Tags: c#, godot4

My Godot 4.2 main scene has a Player + Camera3D working with Rendering set to Compatibility.

I have a UI in a child scene that contains a Sprite2D that I'd like to put the Camera's view into.

I added a SubViewport as the parent to the Camera with size 1280 x 800 and Update Mode Always and at launch this code runs just fine:

```
subViewport = FindChild<dungeon_sub_viewport>();
dungeonSprite2D = FindChild<dungeon_sprite_2d>();
dungeonSprite2D.Texture = subViewport.GetTexture();
```

While running, Remote shows Sprite2D has Texture set to an object ID, but the UI only shows black/blank content.

How do I get the Camera's view/texture to show up in the Sprite2D?